# WKWebView autocomplete suggestions in UITextField

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I am using a WKWebview to display web page and have a UITextField where the user can enter the URL they wish to navigate to (in-app browser of sorts). As the user is typing, I would like to display a list of possibilities (i.e. popular sites). Are there any Apple (or 3rd party) APIs I could use to fetch a list of popular sites based on a substring?

Edit: I need to use a WKWebView as opposed to the new Safari View Controller because I want to be able to inject custom javascript (which is not allowed in the former)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this URL for auto complete**

http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q=YOURQUERY

Like

search?client=chrome&q=apple

**Use TableView For Showing the suggestions.**

```
- (IBAction)act_search:(id)sender {
    if([_txt_search.text length] > 2)
    {

        Code Here ...

        [_tableview reloadData];


    }
    else
    {
        jsonarr = nil;
        [_tableview reloadData];
    }


}
```

Comment: This seems like an unofficial google api (no docs that I could find) and could be terminated at any time as per this article https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/07/update-on-autocomplete-api.html Do you know if there is a similar public API?

Comment: I don't think any official documents are available right now but you can refer this like instead (if it helps). http://shreyaschand.com/blog/2013/01/03/google-autocomplete-api/

Comment: Thanks! This is the best solution at the moment but will keep the question open in case anyone else has alternatives. If by tomorrow nothing happens then this will be the accepted answer :)